# Android Studio - setting TabLayout unchangeable

Tags: android, layout, android-tablayout, togglebutton

I'm creating app which uses TabLayout. I have also ToggleButton there.
Is there a way to unable changing to another tab while this particular button is pressed?

> Update

I have a ToggleButton in an abstract class which extends Fragment:

```
    public void onToggleClicked() {
    btnMicrophone.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (something) {
                        do_something();
                    }else {
                        do_something_else();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

There is also a fragment class which extends the abstract class above. I have some assignments there, method callings, Overrided methods (onCreateView, onViewCreated), etc.

MainActivity is almost all generated from pattern.
Everything works fine, but as I said, I need to unable switching between tabs while my button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with your code, so I can update my answer with the code necessary to solve your problem.

If you are using the new TabLayout (if you are not, you should), you can iterate over your views making them unclickable.

As example code:

```
LinearLayout tabs = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
for(int i = 0; i < tabs.getChildCount(); i++) {
    tabs.getChildAt(i).setClickable(false);
    //This disable all tabs, if you need to disable just specific tabs, you can make some logic to it
}
```